# Нужно написать программку, которая складывает из 2х корзин какие либо объекты в в одну, когда место заканчивается - все

Tags: java

Нужно написать программку, которая складывает из 2х корзин какие либо объекты в в одну, когда место заканчивается - все. Вроде просто, но я почему то запутался. Пишет, что массив расчитан только на 5 элементов и ругается.. Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем ошибка и как ее можно исправить?

```
int korzina_1[] = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1};
        int korzina_2[] = {2, 2, 2, 2, 2};
        int korzina_3[] = new int[5];
        boolean detect = true;
        int i = 0;
        while(detect = true){
            if(korzina_3[i] == 0 && i < korzina_3.length) {
                korzina_3[i] = korzina_1[i];
                i++;
            }else{detect = false;}
            if(korzina_3[i] == 0 && i < korzina_3.length) {
                korzina_3[i] = korzina_2[i];
                i++;
            }else{detect = false;}
        }
        for(int j = 0; j < korzina_3.length; j++){
            System.out.println(korzina_3[j]);
        }
        System.out.println("Запрос доступа на дополнительную корзину");
```

Comment: Я написал, что я хочу и что за ошибку выдает)) Будьте внимательны

Comment: Ваша проблема в коде тут `if(korzina_3[i] == 0 && i < korzina_3.length)`, где вы сначала проверяете значение элемента по индексу, а потом проверяете, что индекс не вышел за пределы массива. Вам надо поменять местами эти условия так `if(i < korzina_3.length && korzina_3[i] == 0)`